# Pass a li tag value to a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi
I have a li tag as follows:

```
<li value="myLi" class="myLi">My element</li>
```

I tried this jquery code:

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("mytext").value=$(this).value;
});
```

knowing that `mytext` is an input of type text, how can I pass the value of the li tag to the input , if it's not possible, how can I use the innerHTML to pass the code between the li tags.

the code that I tried does not work
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what some have said, `value` is indeed a valid attribute for `li` elements, and it's reflected in the `value` property, but it's required to be an *integer* ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)):

> The value attribute, if present, must be a valid integer giving the ordinal value of the list item.
>   
> ...
>   
> If the value attribute is present, user agents must parse it as an integer, in order to determine the attribute's value. If the attribute's value cannot be converted to a number, the attribute must be treated as if it was absent. The attribute has no default value.

If your pasted code was just a quick edit and you really will be using an integer, then your code would work if you *didn't* wrap `this` in a jQuery instance:

HTML:

```
<li value="3" class="myLi">My element</li>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('myText').value=this.value;
    // Or
    // $('#myText').attr('value', this.value);
});
```

If you want to use a string, probably best to stick with the new [HTML5 `data-` prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

HTML:

```
<li data-value="myLi" class="myLi">My element</li>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('myText').value=$(this).attr('data-value');
    // Or
    // $('#myText').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

Comment: That's why the value attribute appears in the list of attributes of li in dreamweaver, thank you for this reply.

Answer (score 3):

<del>AFAIK `value` is not valid attribute for `li` elements.</del> (*Not entirely true, see [@T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413710/pass-a-li-tag-value-to-a-text-input/4413791#4413791)*)
 You can use `rel` though:

```
<li rel="myLi" class="myLi">My element</li>
```

And to set the value of the input element, use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    $("#mytext").val($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

If you want to get the text from the `li` element instead, use `$(this).text()`.

Reference: [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Or you could use `data-value` (HTML5) and `$(this).data('value')`. Although it's syntactically incorrect in pre-HTML5 to inject extra attributes, it's harmless on all browsers and versions that I'm aware of. Using `data-value` instead of `value` happens to also make it syntactically valid for an HTML5 doctype.

Comment: *"T.J. Coder's answer"* LOL!! Freudian slip?

Comment: @TJCrowder: Yep :) Sorry... Itried to change it before you see it,  but my internet connection is pretty bad :D

Comment: @Felix: Dude, no worries, made me laugh. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder: At least one of us can laugh about my bad internet connection ;) :D

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$(".myLi").click(function() {
  $("#myText").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: You missed your close paren and semi-colon :)

Comment: and @Ender I think the OP is asking to take a value from an attribute on the `li` (in this case the syntactically-invalid `value` attribute), not the text of the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    $('#mytext').val($(this).text());
});
```

Here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/QdWxH/

Or if you wanted the val from that value attribute: <del>As Felix points out, value isn't a valid attribute of `<li>`.</del> (See @T.J. Crowder's answer)  You could change that to `data-value`, like so:

```
<li data-value="myLi" class="myLi">My element</li>
```

Then do this:

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    $('#mytext').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/BHrmR/

Answer (score 0):

You can use global attribute 'title' for quick and easy.

```
<li title="myLi" class="myLi">My element</li>
```

then

```
$(".myLi").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('myText').value=this.attr('title');
});
```

Hope this help.